# setBusy not executing

Tags: sapui5

I have setBusy exucuting elsewhere in my application, but why not here....

This is reading in my site details, so without the setbusy the page looks like it's doing nothing.

```
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
//initialise display
var view = this.getView();
view.setBusy(true);

view.byId("shopInput").setValue("");
view.byId("effectiveDateFrom").setValue("");
view.byId("shop24Hrs").setSelected(false);
view.byId("shopClosed").setSelected(false);
view.byId("createNext").setVisible(false);
view.byId("createSubmit").setVisible(false);
//view.byId("createSave").setVisible(false);

// initialise the store view model
var oModel = this.getModel("site");

this.getModel().read("/SiteSet", {
success: function (oData) {
var oSiteData = oModel.getData();
oSiteData.Sites = oData.results;
oModel.setData(oSiteData);
}.bind(this)
});
view.setBusy(false);

},
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code sets busy but resets it right away. The read method is asynchronous. You have to reset busy inside the success callback function (it could be a good idea to reset it in an error callback too).

```js
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
//initialise display
var view = this.getView();
view.setBusy(true);

view.byId("shopInput").setValue("");
view.byId("effectiveDateFrom").setValue("");
view.byId("shop24Hrs").setSelected(false);
view.byId("shopClosed").setSelected(false);
view.byId("createNext").setVisible(false);
view.byId("createSubmit").setVisible(false);
//view.byId("createSave").setVisible(false);

// initialise the store view model
var oModel = this.getModel("site");

this.getModel().read("/SiteSet", {
  success: function (oData) {
    var oSiteData = oModel.getData();
    oSiteData.Sites = oData.results;
    oModel.setData(oSiteData);
    view.setBusy(false);
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(){
    view.setBusy(false);
  }
});

},
```

---

Generally when using setBusy() you should mind this points:

- Per default the busy indicator is displayed 1000 milliseconds after `setBusy(true)`. There is a [`setBusyIndicatorDelay()`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#setBusyIndicatorDelay) function to control that delay (can be set to 0).
- The busy indicator is always created deferred (using `setTimeout()`). JavaScript is singlethreaded. So if your code after calling `setBusy()` blocks, the busy indicator will not be displayed until your code has finished and the control flow is returned to the event loop. So don't try this: `setBusy(true); model.loadData("/data", false /*synchronous*/); setBusy(false);`

Comment: I have faced this issue too. I have tried `setBusy(false)` in callback functions, unfortunately it doesn't work. It sets the view *busy* for fraction of a second, **after** AJAX request is completed. 
So possible solution to set the view to busy state would be using [BusyDialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.BusyDialog.html)

Comment: Thank you. As you say it was setting busy to false straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a busy dialog object and then use open and close function in the success call back and error call back respectively. Please have a look at the code:-

```
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
//initialise display
var busyDialog= new sap.m.BusyDialog;
view.byId("shopInput").setValue("");
view.byId("effectiveDateFrom").setValue("");
view.byId("shop24Hrs").setSelected(false);
view.byId("shopClosed").setSelected(false);
view.byId("createNext").setVisible(false);
view.byId("createSubmit").setVisible(false);
//view.byId("createSave").setVisible(false);

// initialise the store view model
var oModel = this.getModel("site");
busyDialog.open();
this.getModel().read("/SiteSet", {
success: function (oData) {
busyDialog.close();    
var oSiteData = oModel.getData();

oSiteData.Sites = oData.results;
oModel.setData(oSiteData);
}.bind(this)
});
busyDialog.close();

},
```